# How to get the line a difference is shown in pear class Horde_Text_Diff?

Tags: php, pear

I am working with `Horde_Text_Diff` and I trying to find differences using PHP.
My code is working but I wondered how I can get the exact line where the differences where found.

Is it something I can calculate from the output?

For the output I get something like this in beginning:

```
-78,9 +78,9
```

Any help would be really cool.

Comment: can you provide your working code . Please so i can try to improve the functioning . thanks

Comment: [Unified diff format](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/diffutils.html#Detailed-Unified).